# Constructing a vector with 6N elements in python

Tags: python, list, vector

So I am trying to define a vector with 6N length such that it looks as such:

{x_0,...,X_(N-1),y_0,...,y_(N-1),z_0,...z_(N-1),v_x0,...,v_x(N-1),v_y0,...,v_y(N-1),v_z0,...,v_z(N-1)}

I understand that I can make an N element vector by

```
N = #some number#
w = [None] * N
```

but having the 6N confuses me (probably more than it should). I am pretty new to all this so I appreciate your help, ultimately I will have to compute the derivative of some elements in the vector, but one step at a time! Thank you!

Comment: `w = [None] * N * 6` ?

Answer (score 0):

The way i understand you problem. You need to put N element from each variable x,y,x,vx,vy,vz in a list.

It can be done this way:

```
x= [None]*N
y= [None]*N
.
.
vz=[None]*N

final_list = x + y + z + vx + vy + vz
```